# associate fee reverstal with transaction

Tags: paypal

I am using transaction search to return a list of transaction. With refunds it is returning two lines the refund and the fee reversal. There is no detailed info available for the fee reversal transaction, so how can I associate the reversal with the refund?

Answer (score 0):

Use the oarent_txn field. It refers to the txn_id of the original transaction which has been reversed, and which you have already received and should have saved.